# Why result sucess (if method) is not working in handleSignInResult method in gmail authentication in android?

Tags: android, gmail

Result success is not working in handleSignInResult method in gmail authentication API in android How to resolve this issue ?

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    //If the login succeed
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        //Getting google account
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

        //Displaying name and email
        textViewName.setText(acctount.getDisplayName());
        textViewEmail.setText(account.getEmail());

        //Initializing image loader
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
            .getImageLoader();

        imageLoader.get(account.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePhoto,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        profilePhoto.setImageUrl(account.getPhotoUrl().toString(), imageLoader);
    }

    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check result error request code: 
have to register SHA1 Key?

Comment: Hi i Practise this url example but it throw issue Login failed....https://github.com/probelalkhan/Login-With-Google-Plus-Android

Comment: Please go with "https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/" and "https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating". There are project specific setting required. Hence go step by step through this tutorials.

Comment: Register SHA1 key first.

Comment: Thanks, How to post user details(like User Name and Email) in my own json url in android      URL:   beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4y2NmxAYf

Comment: For Post Request:

`OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
   os.write(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

   os.close();`

Comment: StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,new Response.Listener<String>() {@Override
public void onResponse(String response)  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}) {@Overrideprotected Map<String, String> getParams() {
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(); params.put("UserName", UserName); params.put("Email", Email);
return params;}};

Comment: RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest); }

Comment: Hi Post the url in this method i got response
   [ {"Email": "swifttest41@gmail.com",
    "Id": 61,
    "UserName": "Gowtham Swift",
    "UserRole": "NewUser"
  }
] In this respose how to get "UserRole    and    "how to Validate "UserRole" ..if "UserRole" == Admin go to one page and If "UserRole"== "NewUser"  go to another Page..

Comment: it is JsonArray : So you need to parse accordingly.  `JsonObject j= (JSONObject)response.getJSONArray(key).get(0);
`

Comment: It is not a json array i used Hashmap

Comment: if you want to fetch data from HasMap you can simply use get method.
**Note:** this is array of HashMap due to square brackets

Comment: Ok Thanks,How to hide one button inside another class button click

Comment: @GowthamM
Hi, i am not able to get ur question

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related with OAuth client Ids.
Cross check with client_id. Also try with web client Id. 
My code was working when I integrated web client id in the android app.

Comment: Thanks, How to post user details(like User Name and Email) in my own json url in android URL: beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4y2NmxAYf